# Way to read data from unstructured text file and write into pandas using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am retrieving data from a .png file using teseract-ocr and pushing into a .txt file. Now I want to read the data which have been written into the .txt file which have not been structured.
Below is the format:

XBRWSEDeateaaReeed

```
TransformationName Node AppliedRows AMfectedRows RejectedRowsThroughputRowsSecThroughputBytesSecBytes LastE
FDRLIBABCBALDETAILAMTSREPROCINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCBALDETAILAMTSREPROCESSEDINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCBALDETAILAMTSSOURCEINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCBALDETAILAMTSSOURCEUPDATE FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCBALDETAILAMTSTARGETUPDATEANDINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCBALROWCOUNTSRC FDWSSALTNO1 1 0 1 683 683 0
FDRLIBABCBALROWCOUNTS FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCBALROWCOUNTS2 FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCBALROWCOUNTSREPROCINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
sFDRLIBABCBALROWCOUNTSREPROCESSEDINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
sFDRLIBABCBALROWCOUNTSUPDATE FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCCTRLSYSMSG FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBABCGATEKPRINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
sFDRLIBABCGATEKPRUPDATE FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
sFDRLIBPREFDRAUTOPLCYMANLADJINSUPD FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
sFDRLIBPREFDRAUTOPLCYMANLADJINSERT FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
FDRLIBREPROCFDRUMBPLCYMANLADJ FDWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
S0SQFDRLIBABCBALROWCOUNTS FOWSSALTNO0 0 0 0 0 0
S0STGPLPLCYMANUALADJ FOWSSALTNO3 3 0 3 3933 3933 0
```

I want to read the values for TransformationName AppliedRows AMfectedRows RejectedRows and store it in pandas.

Comment: you don't have the same number of "items" in each row so it's pretty difficult to know what the proper way to parse such a file should be.

Comment: All lines will have same number of items, it somehow got copied in a wrong way-

Comment: First Row - TransformationName Node AppliedRows AMfectedRows RejectedRowsThroughputRowsSecThroughputBytesSecBytes LastE

Comment: And then it will have all the values will be corresponding to the above headers -

Comment: Last row - S0STGPLPLCYMANUALADJ FOWSSALTNO3 3 0 3 3933 3933 0 . @ALollz Kindly let me know if you can suggest something. Also, can you suggest on how to remove the above whitespaces before the data starts in the text file

Comment: Please separate all the columns of the data in the example data and show what you would expect it to look like _if you were to **keep all the columns**_. I would suggest you to use a **`code-block`** to format and show this information. I really don't know where your column headers and column values start and finish. You need to give this clarity, if you expect anyone to give you a reproducible solution. Preferably show this in a comma-separated-value (CSV) format. Also, what do you mean by _"format: XBRWSEDeateaaReeed"_?

Comment: line 7 has 8 fields, while above it all have 7 fields.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem by split based on " " and then insert data into different positions of data frame and then able to read it in the format I need.
Thanks to all for all the comments.